# Index of a differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let's consider an operator $D: C^{m+n}[a, b] \rightarrow C^{m}[a, b]$, defined as $D(y(t)) = y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+a_{1}y'+a_{0}$, $a_{k} \in C^{m}[a, b]$.

I would like to prove that it is a Fredholm operator and evaluate its index. First, it's not so sophisticated to find the dimension of its kernel, according to the statement from ODEs theory -- any solution can be uniquely described as $C_{1}e^{\alpha_{1}t}+C_{2}e^{\alpha_{2}t}+ \ldots C_{n} e^{\alpha_{n}t}$, $\alpha_{n}$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, so the dimension equal $n$.

What goes about dimension of cokernel -- by establishing it's precise dimension we can prove that the operator is Fredholm.

Let's fix a basis $\{e^{inx} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ -- since we know that trigonometric polynomials are dence in $C^{q}[a,b]$, the exponent can be written as a linear combination of the form $P(\cos(bx), \sin(bx))$.

How to find the dimension of an image? (the first step on the road to cokernel). Probably, the idea is to consider the Fouirer series of $y(t)$ with respect to the fixed basis and obtain the exact formula for the derivatives but this does not seem to be very benefitial.

Are there any hints that might help?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a function $f\in C^m[a,b]$ you can always solve the equation
$$
y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_{1}y'+a_{0}=f.
$$
Indeed, you can write the equation in the form $$x'=Ax+h(t),
$$
for some $n\times n$ matrix $A$, where
$$
x=(y,y',\ldots,y^{(n-1)})^T\quad\text{and}\quad h(t)=(0,\ldots,0,f(t)).
$$
It follows from the variation-of-parameters formula that the latter has a solution, and $y$ is given by the first component of $x$. So the cokernel is trivial.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks.